# text editor in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

i have a sdk 3.1.2 and is there any framework or class or delegate methods or protocols to add text in our UIImageView???. if there exist then guid me!!!!

Comment: ok!! actually i am new to this. .

Comment: Read the faq - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: i will take care of this in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Detect the touch on image using

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

2.At the touched location add a UITextField and let the user enter his text.
3.When is done writing the text merge ImageView and TextField.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImageView.frame.size);
    [myImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [mytextField.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshotImage, self, (SEL)@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: method 'renderInContext' is not found!! I think some headers to be included!!

Comment: which protocols or headers to be added, to identify renderInContext method?

Comment: does any body knows solution to this problem??

Comment: My UITextView is not showing proper location where i actually want to save on UIImage view. Its showing at top upper left corner

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is when you create imageView set userInteractionEnabled = YES; now create textView or TextField  addsubview for imageView.

I am sure it works..